# Creating websocket server with boost.beast

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, websocket, boost-asio

I want to create simple boost.beast websocket server which accept connection saves pointer to it and and when someone is connecting send message to every connected socket.

I've taken code from boost.beast async_server example: https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast/blob/master/example/websocket-server-async/websocket_server_async.cpp

And added:

`static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<connection>> server::players_connections`;

and

```
void server::connection::send_message(std::string msg){
            boost::beast::ostream(buffer_) << msg;
            ws_.binary(ws_.got_binary());
            ws_.async_write(buffer_.data(),
                            strand_.wrap(std::bind(
                                    &connection::on_write,
                                    shared_from_this(),
                                    std::placeholders::_1)));
        }
```

At the end of void server::connection::on_read(error_code ec) method i've added

```
 for(auto  player : server::players_connections){
                player->send_message("already accepted");
            }
```

and at the end of server::connection::on_accept:

```
players_connections.push_back(std::make_shared<connection>(*this, ep_, std::move(sock_)));
        players_connections.back()->run();
```

When second socket connects i have this error:

```
websocket-server-async: /usr/local/boost_1_64_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/pausation.hpp:210: void boost::beast::websocket::detail::pausation::emplace(F&&) [with F = boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::write_some_op<boost::beast::buffer_prefix_view<boost::beast::consuming_buffers<boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char> >::const_buffers_type> >, boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::write_op<boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char> >::const_buffers_type, boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (server::connection::*)(boost::system::error_code)>(std::shared_ptr<server::connection>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>, boost::asio::detail::is_continuation_if_running> > >]: Assertion `! base_' failed.
Aborted
```

Full modified code of server: http://morse.swirski.name/pastes/vrv552rf2yc7fyyflxhejukjdpr4vxe

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug was because i was calling

```
ws_.async_write(buffer_.data(),
                            strand_.wrap(std::bind(
                                    &connection::on_write,
                                    shared_from_this(),
                                    std::placeholders::_1)));
```

two times in a row an this was causing the problem. I am not sure why. I suspect that method do_read called one after another was causing the problem. I would appriciate any suggestions.

Comment: The examples have been improved, check it out:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a non-blocking Boost::Beast based WebSocket library that simplifies WebSockets integration.

It's called [WebSockets-Callback.CPP available on GitHub](https://github.com/aidv/websockets-callback.cpp).